# Clip lines to plot area and display text outside plot area

Tags: r, graphics, plot, ggplot2

I want to restrict the visible y-range of my plot. In order to retain values that fall outside this range I need to set `oob` (*out of bounds*) to `rescale_none` and this works well.

However I would also like to add some text in the margins outside the plot. In order to do this I need to turn off clipping. This has the effect that values that are out-of-bounds are plotted outside the plot area in the margins.

**Is there anyway to plot text in margins *and* clip values to plot region?**

```
#  Data
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame( x=1:100,y=rnorm(100,mean=1,sd=1) )
# Basic plot

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(grid)

g <- ggplot(df)+
geom_line(aes(x,y))


#  Values exceeding scale limits are dropped
g1 <- g + scale_y_continuous( limits = c(0,2) )
```

[image: OOB values dropped]

```
#  This is what I want
g2 <- g + scale_y_continuous( limits = c(0,2) , oob = rescale_none )
```

[image]

```
#  ...But, I would like to plot some text outside the plotting region
#  and need to turn off clipping to get the text to display...
g3 <- g + scale_y_continuous( limits = c(0,2) , oob = rescale_none ) +
    # Some text to sit above the plot
    geom_text( aes(label = "Nonsense", y = Inf, x = 0), hjust = 0, vjust = -1) +
    # Add some space for the text
    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(2,1,1,1), "lines")) 

#  Turning off clipping makes geom_line also go outside plot area...
#  See here for clipping... http://stackoverflow.com/a/12417481/1478381
g4 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g3))
g4$layout$clip[g4$layout$name == "panel"] <- "off"

grid.draw(g4)
```

[image]

Comment: doesn't coord_cartesian + clipping do this

Comment: @rawr no. Same problem.

Comment: hm, the only other thing I've done similar is to create another plot with just the text and sort of stack the two together. I'm sure that wizard @baptiste would know of something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With an approach from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997715/add-ggplot-annotation-outside-the-panel-or-two-titles), here's my solution:

```
library(gtable)
gg <- ggplotGrob(g2)
gg <- gtable_add_grob(gg, textGrob("Nonsense", x=0, hjust=0), t=1, l=4)
grid.draw(gg)
```

[image]

Comment: I have run into the same issue except my 'Nonsense' has to be in the middle which I figured out byt changing t and l value. However I need it to be a different color form the ORIGINAL title!! That is what's puzzling me

Answer (score 0):

Use `ggplot2::labs()`. The last version of ggplot2 includes this function to print title, subtitle and captions on each graph.

`p = ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, colour = cyl)) + geom_point()
p + labs(colour = "Cylinders")
p + labs(x = "New x label", title='Plot title', caption='Source: IMF.')`

Source: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/1582